# Active Desktop Recovery Issue

Tags: windows, windows-xp, registry, desktop

My Desktop shows "Active Desktop Recovery" screen.

When I click on "Restore my active desktop button", I get a script error which says "Object doesn't support this property or method".

The url field in the error popup box shows path to Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Desktop.htt file.

However on going to that folder, there is no such file.

How to resolve this issue?

I do not have admin rights on the pc and thus can not open regedit. Is there any other way to solve this.

Tried changing the desktop resolution and switching back. But this is also not working.

Comment: @downvoter: Its a common problem which we face... Couldn't find the solution on SO... So raised a question... why downvote ?

Comment: this question is not "about programming", should be on superuser.com not here, that's why someone downvoted I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue in following way:

I went to Desktop.htt file in C:/Documents and Settings//Application Data/Microsoft/Internet Explorer in my other system where desktop recovery issue is not there. I copied the contents of the file and mailed it.

I went to the same file on the system having desktop recovery issue and replaced the content of Desktop.htt file with the mailed contents.

Desktop.htt file is a system protected file. So to view it, we have to uncheck two check boxes in folder options : 1) View hidden files and folders and 2) View system protected files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(You don't need admin rights to edit HKCU)

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\SafeMode\Components`

Change `DeskHtmlVersion` to `0`.

Another possibility:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\SafeMode\Components"
strValue = "0"
ValueName = "DeskHtmlVersion"
objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, ValueName, strValue
```

Paste that in notepad and save it as *filename*.vbs and run it. I'm not sure if this will invoke regedit some way or it might use Win32 API so it's worth a shot.

Hope this helps!

Comment: nice answer but i think the OP meant he cannot `open regedit` to modify the values

Comment: @PresleyDias Ah maybe, wasn't sure if he meant permission to edit or if it had been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me for Windows XP.

Copy the below code in a text file and save it as IE7.vbs on desktop. (Obviously you can choose any other name)

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\SafeMode\Components"
strValue = "0"
ValueName = "DeskHtmlVersion"
objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, ValueName, strValue
```

Now double click on the file IE7.vbs which is now at your desktop.

The issue is resolved immediately. :)

Please give the feedback if it works for u.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for those who haven't the Registy Folder "Desktop".

you have on the Windows XP Screen where you can change you desktop image the possibility to customize. Choose that, the Tab "Web" maybe there is really an active object for the active desktop.